# Different between while i and j / while j and i in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to do leetcode #83
The thing I don't understand is that what's a difference between the following two ways:

```
    while cur and cur.next:

    while cur.next and cur:
```

If I try the second way, it will appear compile error.
Can anyone help me to understand this concept?

```
    # Definition for singly-linked list.
    # class ListNode(object):
    #     def __init__(self, x):
    #         self.val = x
    #         self.next = None

    class Solution(object):
        def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
            """
            :type head: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    cur= head
    while cur and cur.next:
        if cur.val== cur.next.val:
            cur.next= cur.next.next
        else: 
            cur = cur.next

    return(head)
```

I am the beginner of data structure. 
I still confuse why cur.next is error way. The code cur = head didn't works?

Comment: Just a tip for you and readers: Comparison for `None` should [definitely be done with `is`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): `while cur is not None and cur.next is not None`.

Comment: Disagree. `while cur and cur.next` is idiomatic. PEP8 only says to use `is` rather than `==` when comparing to `None`. It doesn't insist that one use `value is not None` over simply `value`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [short circuit evaluation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If cur is None, the interpreter won't even try to check cur.next.

Comment: I still confuse why cur.next is error way. The code cur = head didn't works? Why cur is None?

Comment: @Esther you loop through a linked list, when you reach the end, cur will become None because of `cur = cur.next`.